# android image wrapped by text

Tags: android, text, image

I would like to insert image into text, for example:

I would like to show the text likie this:

"To edit picture you should click on" [image] "button."

Where [image] is real image (e.g. ImageView)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this,i donot know if this is your need:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main); 
            TextView textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); 
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc"); 
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon32); 


            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
            ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
            ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 


            textView.setText(ss);
```