# Show Image in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I wish to show Images in TextView. My Images are saved in res/raw directory. I tried using HTML.ImageGetter but could not find a complete reference for same.

Comment: why do you need this? There is always an ImageView UI component in Android

Comment: Why do you want to put an image in a textview. why not instead wrap the textview in some other layout (say a linearLayout), and add an imageview as a sibling. it will make managing the appearance of both pieces much easier.

Comment: A TextView is made for displaying text. You can try using a WebView with a transparent background

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328476/android-image-wrapped-by-text

Comment: I am using an activity which has a textview. TextView need to display text which changes, few of them has images other don't have therefore I need to use images in TextView. This can be done with HTML.ImageGetter.Android documentation states "Retrieves images for HTML <img> tags".

Comment: You absolutely do not need to put it in a textview. use textview for text, and imageview for images. just simply set the visibility/content of your imageviews dynamically based on your needs. adding a sibling imageview to your textview will make your layout more reusable/easier to read or modify/easier to change. use View.setVisibility(View.GONE|View.VISIBLE) to enable/disable the imageview in question

Comment: @davs your suggestion works but I need to insert HTML in TextView and Images selectively on case by case basis.

Comment: @Slothsberry My apps has questions and answers and I don't know the location of the image it can be at between the text anywhere, end of text or beginning of text therefore I need to insert image in text. I can instead use WebView, which I wish to avoid. Visibility as suggested by you does not solve my particular problem.

Comment: so you essentially have some string that you want to display, and encoded somewhere in this string is a tag to an image that should be displayed inline?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Html.ImageGetter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextImageActivity extends Activity {
    int imageNumber = 1; //int to check which image is displayed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    final String testContent = "<html><body><b>Test</b><i>Italic</i><br/>"
            + "<img src=\"icon.png\"/>This is like testing if this thing works" + "<img src=\"a.png\"/>" +
                    " in a more elaborate</body></html>";
    tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(testContent, imgGetter, null));
}

  private ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = null;
            if(imageNumber == 1) {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.icon);
            ++imageNumber;
            } else drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.a);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
                                    .getIntrinsicHeight());

            return drawable;
    }
 };

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try so you don't have to hack your use of TextView. This will allow you to account for an arbitrary number of images tagged in the source string. it will also allow for adjacent images, and allow for empty leading or trailing text strings.

```
LinearLayout parent = //get parent layout
String input = //get input
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
int imageIndex = input.indexOf("<image tag begin");
int endIndex = -1; //find index one past the end of the image tag
while (imageIndex > -1){
    TextView tv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_textview, null);
    tv.setText(input.substring(0, imageIndex));

    ImageView iv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_imageview, null);
    String imgTag = input.substring(imageIndex,endIndex);
    iv.setImageResource(-1); //or however you set your image from the tag

    parent.addView(tv); parent.addView(iv);

    input = input.substring(endIndex);
    }
```

This should dynamically create all the imageviews you  need, and parse your inputs accordingly. if you want to store the source strings in the DB, that's probably fine.

Keeping text in textviews and images in imageviews will make your life far easier if you have to set styles/modify attributes on anything involved. Sibling views are, in general, better than hacking the wrong kind of information/too much information into one Layout element.

BTW, i inflated custom XML layouts for imageview and textview, just in case you wanted to provide some custom style settings across all instances of them. you can just generate normal Android textviews and imageviews if those are sufficient.

This was my initial solution that only works with a single image maximum.

> ```
> String input = //whatever
> boolean hasImage = //find image tag
> int imageBegin = //find index where image tag begins
> int imageEnd = //find index one past where image tag ends
> String leadingText = input.substring(0,imageBegin);
> String imageTag = input.substring(imageBegin, imageEnd);
> String trailingText = input.substring(imageEnd, input.length());
>
> ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.leading_textview)).setText(leadingText);
> if (hasImage){
>     //use imageTag to set content of Image View)
>     findViewById(R.id.image_view_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.trailing_textview)).setText(trailingText);
> }
> ```
>
> If you could have more than one image embedded, you'll have to
>   dynamically create ImageViews and trailing TextViews, and add them to
>   the parent of the layout in question.

Comment: you proposed answer is very impressive. The TextView in my case comes from a SQLite database, if I implement your solution maintaining database will become very complex. Android has developed a class HTML.ImageGetter. I believe using it can be useful in my case.

Comment: it should be just as easy. I imagine your SQLiteDB is basically a key-value mapping between Unique IDs and the string value. and the string values look something like "texttexttetxt<img tag>texttexttext". you can not modify your storage at all, and simply parse out this value into the 3 views whenever you need to display to the user

Comment: Or, if you want to break up your database, just store the 3 components of the string: leading, image, and trailing, in separate columns in the same table.

Comment: @Slothberry there are multiple possibilities 1."<img tag>taxtexttext" 2."text<img tag>texttext<img tag>"3.texttext<img tag><img tag>". I don't want to limit myself with how many and where I need to insert the image. It should go anywhere and as many as need be.

Comment: @Slothberry your technique can be used but how we will know the index past image and how we will set the image located in the local directory. I have found a solution useful for my purpose.I appreciate your technique.

Comment: just search for the end of tag. "/>". i have no idea where your images are (online, resources, whatever), but if you don't know how to use imageview, that's another question. Embedding an image in a textview is very likely to lead you to trouble, so this is the better way

Answer (score 0):

u can use this: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

[follow this example](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/06/display-iconimage-on-button-using-java.html)  u can do the same for textview

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. How it can be used to insert multiple images in a TextView.